# jQuery gmap is not showing on website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dictionary, jquery-gmap3

I downloaded a template that had gmap already integrated into it. All I had to do was adjust the markers so that it pointed to the right location.

I am in the process of creating a new website, and on the contact page, I want to add the same gmap that is on the template.

I used the same code, copied over the same files and put them in their respective directories, but I cannot get the map to show up on my page.

In the HEAD of the HTML document, I have included this code:

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

Further down in the BODY, I have created a SECTION tag like this:

```
 <section id="map-section">
      <div id="map"></div>
 </section>
```

Just above the closing BODY tag, I have these pieces of Javascript:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.gmap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#map').gMap(
      {
        latitude: 50.000000,
        longitude: 50.000000,
        html: "My Location",
        popup: true,
        panControl: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions:
        {
          style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
        },
        mapTypeControl: true,
        scaleControl: true,
        streetViewControl: false,
        overviewMapControl: true,
        scrollwheel: true,
        icon:
        {
          image: "http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker.png",
          shadow: "http://www.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png",
          iconsize: [20, 34],
          shadowsize: [37, 34],
          iconanchor: [9, 34],
          shadowanchor: [19, 34]
        },
        zoom:15,
        markers: [{
          latitude: 50.000000,
          longitude: 50.000000
        }]
      });
    });
 </script>
```

Also, in my CSS, I have the MAP-SECTION looking like this:

```
#map-section {
  bottom: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#map{
  display: block;
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width:1350px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

If you notice in the CSS, in the `#map-section`, I have included a red border which does show on the screen. It's just not showing the map.

Can anyone see what I am missing?

Please help.

Comment: Are there any javascript errors if you debug it in your browser?

Answer (score 0):

Include all js files mentioned here in script tag.
         maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false,
         jquery.ui.map.js,
         jquery.ui.map.extensions.js,
         jquery.ui.map.overlays.js,
         jquery.ui.map.services.js

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:500px;"></div>

var mapa = $('#map_canvas').gmap({'center': '-18.646245,35.815918'});
        $('#map_canvas').gmap('option', 'zoom', 7);

        //create the layer (all countries except Mozambique)
        var world_geometry;
        $('#map_canvas').gmap().bind('init', function(event, map) {
            world_geometry = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
                query: {
                    select: 'geometry',
                    from: '1N2LBk4JHwWpOY4d9fobIn27lfnZ5MDy-NoqqRpk',
                    where: "ISO_2DIGIT NOT EQUAL TO 'MZ'"
                },
                styles: [{
                        polygonOptions: {
                            fillColor: "#333333",
                            fillOpacity: 0.3
                        }
                    }],
                map: map,
                suppressInfoWindows: true
            });

        });

            $('#map_canvas').gmap().bind('init', function(event, map) {
                $(map).click(function(event) {
                    $('#map_canvas').gmap('clear', 'markers');
                    $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {
                        'position': event.latLng,
                        'draggable': true,
                        'bounds': false
                    }, function(map, marker) {
                    }).dragend(function(event) {
                        google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(event.latLng,                       world_geometry);
                    }).click(function() {
                    })
                });
            });
```

for live demo check this jsfidlle "http://jsfiddle.net/Lq2p5/"

Comment: I added/included all of the files you referenced above, and I used the same DIV you used above, but nothing is being displayed on my page.  Any thoughts?

Comment: have checked it on the fiddle? I think its an issue with the browser.Check the console of the browser for the errors.